# Event and pairwise independence

Tags: conditional-probability

There are $n$ people for each $i ϵ \{1,\ldots,n\}$.
$A_i$ is the event that a person $i$ experiences.
Suppose $P[ A_i ] = \frac1{2i+1}$  , $A_i$  and $A_j$ are independent whenever $i \neq j$ . what are the lower and higher bounds for $P[ A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 ]$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.